# how to get the list of jobs in Jenkins using java?

Tags: java, jenkins

I have downloaded and configured Jenkins in a server, my problem is that i need to access Jenkins through Java to perform some process such as starting a job, returning the current working job and returning list of jobs in the server(all that using Json) i've tried several codes such as [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients) but im getting no results, also i cant find a clear way to achieve that, is there is any clear API and example to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Jenkins API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) over XML:

```
    import org.dom4j.io.*;
    import org.dom4j.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            URL url = new URL("http://your-hudson-server.local/hudson/api/xml");
            Document dom = new SAXReader().read(url);

            for( Element job : (List<Element>)dom.getRootElement().elements("job")) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Job %s has status %s",
                    job.elementText("name"), job.elementText("color")));
            }
        }
    }
```

A complete example (with sources) can be found [here](http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/jvnet/hudson/client-demo/).

If these examples don't work, you might have problems with Jenkins Security (your client must provide login data before it can send the request)or with CSRF protection (you have to retrieve a token before the first request and add this token as a parameter to each request).

Comment: Thank you @stefan you've answered my question, but how to create a job in jenkins i've tried this http://hudsonserver:8080/createItem?name=newjobname" but it doesn't work

Comment: The correct URL should look like this: "HUDSON_URL/job/JOBNAME/build?token=TOKEN" (see https://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Hudson/Remote_access_API#Submitting_jobs for details)