# How to get the status of a Jenkins job in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jenkins

I want to get the status of a job in jenkins through java.

Is there any API which I can refer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the list of jobs in Jenkins using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086380/how-to-get-the-list-of-jobs-in-jenkins-using-java)

Comment: Dave, I actually want the status of one of the jenkins job. In other words, Whether the job is currently running or executed. If so, what was the status and console log. I think it is different from the suggestion. Please let me know if I am right?

Comment: ajc, there are several other very similar questions on this site that should give you the pointers you need to find a solution (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12944403/172599, http://stackoverflow.com/q/14843874/172599).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yah, right here
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API is the API reference

Comment: I did land on this link, but there are no endpoints for the api. All that is mentioned is - "That is, there is no single entry point for all features, and instead they are available under the ".../api/" URL where "..." portion is the data that it acts on."

Comment: Because it depends on your version and plugins. So, do what it says, point to your jenkins URL, some job, and then just put "/api/" at the end of the URL and you will see all the available end points

Answer (score 1):

You can get if the build is successful or failure using the below REST api link:

http://myJenkinsMachine/job/someJob/api/xml 
You will get the below xml with color of the build (blue or any other color):

```
<freeStyleProject>

<description/>

<displayName>someJob</displayName>

<name>someJob</name>

<url>http://myJenkins/job/someJob/</url>

**<buildable>true</buildable>**

<build>

<number>4</number>

<url>http://myJenkins/job/someJob/4/</url>

</build>

<build>

<number>3</number>

<url>http://myJenkins/job/someJob/3/</url>

</build>

<build>

<number>2</number>

<url>http://myJenkins/job/someJob/2/</url>

</build>

<build>

<number>1</number>

<url>http://myJenkins/job/someJob/1/</url>

</build>

<color>blue</color>

<firstBuild>

<number>1</number>

<url>http://myJenkins/job/someJob/1/</url>

</firstBuild>

<healthReport>

<description>Build stability: No recent builds failed.</description>

<iconUrl>health-80plus.png</iconUrl>

<score>100</score>

</healthReport>

<inQueue>false</inQueue>

<keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>

<lastBuild>

<number>4</number>

<url>http://myJenkins/job/someJob/4/</url>

</lastBuild>

<lastCompletedBuild>

<number>4</number>

<url>http://myJenkins/job/someJob/4/</url>

</lastCompletedBuild>

<lastStableBuild>

<number>4</number>

<url>http://myJenkins/job/someJob/4/</url>

</lastStableBuild>

<lastSuccessfulBuild>

<number>4</number>

<url>http://myJenkins/job/someJob/4/</url>

</lastSuccessfulBuild>

<lastUnsuccessfulBuild>

<number>3</number>

<url>http://myJenkins/job/someJob/3/</url>

</lastUnsuccessfulBuild>

<nextBuildNumber>5</nextBuildNumber>

<concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>

<scm/>

</freeStyleProject>
```

OR

http://myJenkinsMachine/job/someJob/api/xml?depth=4 - to get more details upto level 4 - whether building or not

```
<freeStyleProject>
<description/>
<displayName>somejob</displayName>
<name>somejob</name>
<url>http://myJenkins/job/somejob/</url>
<allBuild>
<action>
<cause>
<shortDescription>Started by user ancd</shortDescription><userId>ancd</userId><userName>ancd</userName></cause></action><action/>
**<building>false</building>**
<duration>236018</duration>
```